# Long running php script failing as a cron

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have written a PHP script that uploads images from a directory to a remote server using ftp_put. I have set this as a cron using task scheduler and wget. Initially it works great, but then after a while, do not know exactly when, the process freezes, by that "windows task scheduler" saying it is running the job, but no photos are no longer being uploaded.

Initially I thought the problem was due the max_execution_time , but I have set that to 24 hours by using set_time_limit(3600*24); and I have set max_input_time to 600 seconds (10 mins).

Why doesn't it complete the task?

Here is the code:

```
if($conn){
    if (is_dir($imagesPath)){
        if($files = opendir($imagesPath)){
            while(($file = readdir($files)) !== false){
                if($file != "." && $file != ".." && preg_match("/\.jpg|\.JPG|\.gif|\.GIF|\.png|\.PNG|\.bmp|\.BMP/",$file) && date("Ymd",filemtime($imagesPath.'/'.$file)) >= date("Ymd",strtotime(date("Y-m-d")." -".$days." day"))){
                    if(ftp_put($conn, $remotePath.$file, $imagesPath.'/'.$file, FTP_BINARY)){
                        //echo $file;
                        $counter++;
                    }
                    else{
                        echo '<br>'.$imagesPath.'/'.$file;
                    }
                }
            }
            closedir($files);
            echo $counter.' Files Uploaded on '.date("Y-m-d");
        }
        else{
            echo 'Unable to read '.$imagesPath;
        }
    }
    else{
        echo $imagesPath.' Does not exist';
    }
    ftp_close($conn);
}else{
    echo "Failed to connect";
}
/* End */
exit;
```

Added:

```
/* Settings */
// Set Max Execution time
set_time_limit(3600*24);
```

at the top of the script.

Thanks.

Comment: have you checked logs? have you set up cron job to save output to some log file?

Comment: Without seeing the code, impossible to say. Have the script spit out some debugging/logging statements at each major state, and see what the last stage was before it locks up.

Comment: Try breaking the tasks down and add debug messages, so you can see if the connection fails or the upload etc. - Maybe the upload limit (total allowed storage) is reached at some point? - I think we need more information here.

Comment: We need to see the code. If task scheduler says the process is running, it is running. Your code has probably just got stuck in a loop unable to do something, or is waiting for something with an infinite timeout. It's definitely *not* anything to do with `max_execution_time` because a) this does not apply in CLI mode and b) if this expires the process terminates - task scheduler would not show it as running.

Comment: The only log I checked was the one provided in the task scheduler, I haven't as of yet added the parameter for logging using wget, not to sure how to do this, I tried ‘-o C:\log’ but it didn't create the file and log it. thanks.

Comment: added code. See original post, edited it.

Comment: How often is this scheduled to run? You may be hitting a server limit on connect frequency, or encountering issues due to parallel execution (not sure if Task Scheduler protects against that)

Comment: DaveRandom could the issue be related to the ftp_put function timing out after a while?

Comment: @bobo Well, you could try calling [`ftp_set_option($conn, FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC, 10);`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-set-option.php) to reduce the default 90 second timeout to 10 seconds, and see if that helps...

Comment: If I reduce the timeout to 10 secs, wont that mean the script will timeout quicker?

Comment: Yes, but if that starts causing your script to terminate, you know it's a probably a problem with the FTP server rather than your script. You could also try using `file_put_contents()` with a full FTP url, instead of using the FTP extension. What I would probably do is get out [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and have a look at the network traffic between your script and the FTP server, to see if there are any clues there...

Comment: Ok after running the script in the browser window I get the error: The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout . I changed the php.ini to ini_set('max_execution_time',6000); and 
<fastCgi>
  <application fullPath="<path>" arguments="<args>" activityTimeout="<value"> ...<otherValues>.... />
</fastCgi> modified that in the iis file by increasing the activity timeout time. Yet it still times out after every 15 minutes why? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am working on something similar and I found the following to help:

1) make sure every step is conditional so if something fails to load (like an image, ftp connection etc.) the procedure keeps running (iterating).

2) set a small `sleep()` at the end of the file (or between difficult steps). I am using it for images as well and when the connection to the image lags or the 'image write' time lags it helps.

3) set the scheduler to execute the script often (my is 2 times a day) but it could be set to hourly as long as you check the box: **do not start new instance if the script is already running**

4) depending on the setup of your server, check for other tasks which may interrupt the script run-time. It is not always PHP issue. As long as you have properly scheduled task to re-execute the script you should be fine.

5) for easy debugging, instead of the echo statement (which is most likely showing in your cmd window) use a simple file logging like ( `$message = fopen($myLogFile, 'w');` )  additionally to your "Does not exist" or "Failed to connect" statements and include more details so when it fails, you can go to your log file and see when and why it failed.

6) you may try to use an infinite loop like ( `while (true) { ... your code... }`) instead of `the set_time_limit()`.

I hope this helps :)